# TypeError: midnight.getTime is not a function

Tags: javascript

I want to get the remaining time until 0 o'clock but I get an error midnight.getTime () is not a function

My Code:

```
let midnight = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
let cooldown = new Date(midnight.getTime() - Date.now())
console.log(`${cooldown.getHours()}:${cooldown.getMinutes()}:${cooldown.getSeconds()}`)
```

Comment: What is `midnight` here? Was the variable declared earlier in the code? If so please post the entire code.

Comment: @TheWhiteFang It's in the line above

Comment: Take a look at the return value of [`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#return_value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setHours` function of `Date` returns timestamp(in ms) which is a number and doesn't have a `getTime` method. So you should first store the `new Date()` in a variable and then set the time using `setHours` on it.
Code:

```
let midnight = new Date();
midnight.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` gives a number. You should convert it to a Date.

See the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours).

Answer (score 0):

Try separating `setHours()` method from first line. Like below

```
let midnight = new Date();
midnight.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
let cooldown = new Date(midnight.getTime() - Date.now())
```